# How to find custom button in custom UI layout in exoplayer?

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer

I want to custom the UI of [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) using these codes

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/exoplayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/control_view_normal"/>
```

This is [control_view_normal](https://gist.github.com/wu162/7602b0ffb7a77a1929d56f456bec2c87),corresponding to the app:controller_layout_id

Then I try to find the **exo_fullscreen_button** in the code

```
 View controlView = videoView.findViewById(R.id.exo_controller);
 controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button)  
            .setOnClickListener(v -> {           //null pointer exception! why?
                    ((Activity)context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                });
```

Moreover,the compiler gives me a `controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button)` is null pointer.
Someone know how should I find the custom button in the custom layout?

Comment: are your views being rendered? try removing this code and tell me if you see the views you're trying to find

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri I don't get what you mean. If I remove app:controller_layout_id and override the exo_playback_control_view layout ,everything is ok. But I have to use diffrent UI for diffrent activities.

Comment: I meant remove your java block that causes the NullPointerException (the second code block in ur post)

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri Emmm....After I remove these codes,I find my custom layout does not work.It's still the old layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define exo_controller_placeholder too, this should be any dummy view which will be replaced with your custom controller

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/exoplayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/control_view_normal"
    app:exo_controller_placeholder="@+id/view_holder"/>
<View 
    android:id="@+id/view_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you write some codes to show me how to correct this? I 'm not so familiar with exoplayer...

Comment: There you go, checkout the answer again

Comment: still fail....it show   ```AAPT: error: attribute exo_controller_placeholder (aka com.example.videopage:exo_controller_placeholder) not found.```